# javascript - Show function in multiple 'id'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting in javascript.  I have two questions in one.  I would like to show the date in a specific 'id', And use multiple 'id' in a same function.  (data will appear several times in the site)

As: `id="date1" id="date2" id="date3"`

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

I know I have to use this line but I do not know how to apply it:

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML
```

Comment: document.getElementById("date").innerText = today;

Comment: @RomanBobrik Did you mean `textContent`? `innerText` is nonstandard.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It's not non-standard? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText (simply "easily confused with" another element property).

Comment: Huh, so they did end up adding it. I still wouldn't use `innerText` because of its.... oddities. Mostly around linebreaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and its safer cousin [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) are assignable properties which affect the DOM upon assigning.

```
document.getElementById("date").textContent = today;
```

will cause the DOM node which matches the `getElementById("date")` query (i.e. the element in the DOM with the `id=` attribute of `date`), to have its text replaced with the value of `today`.

The reason to prefer `textContent` over `innerHTML` is that `textContent` is less exposed to XSS attacks. (Only use `.innerHTML` when you *intend* to add HTML to a DOM node, and not plain text, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page) and [here](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) for more details on that, although I'd wait until you have better established your JavaScript knowledge). When in doubt, use `textContent` over `innerHTML`.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

document.getElementById('date').textContent = today;
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```